# Connect apiary.io REST API v1+ in Google Data Studio

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, urlfetch, apiary.io

I need to connect [apiary.io REST API v1+](https://piperun.docs.apiary.io/#) to `Google Data Studio`.

As I checked, I need to develop a connector with `JavaScript` in [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/), as I checked in these tutorials [Connect and visualize all your data in Data Studio](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors/#0) and [External APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) .

In this step by step software manufacturer, [piperun REST API v1+](https://piperun.docs.apiary.io/#). There are several code snippets, but I can not make them work in `GDS`.

Unfortunately I do not have much experience with `JavaScript`, my main skill is with `T-SQL`, but I could make the successful connections in `Microsoft PowerBI`. But I was able to make the connections successfully in Microsoft PowerBI by inserting the `URLs` and the `TOKENS`of access, having the return code `200`.

```
function teste() {

  var url = 'https://api.pipe.run/v1/activities';

  var request = UrlFetchApp;

  request.fetch(url); 

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log('Status:', this.status);
      console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
      console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    }
  };

  request.send();

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'https://api.pipe.run/v1/activities/activity_id');

               request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Token', 'Q3VydGl1IGVzc2Ugam9iPyEgdHJhYmFsaGVjb25vc2NvQHBpcGUucnVu'); // Here I add TOKEN supplied internally by the application

  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log('Status:', this.status);
      console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
      console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    }
  };

  request.send();  
}
```

And even if you enter a valid `TOKEN`, the error occurs:

> Failed to request https://api.pipe.run/v1/activities returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"success": false, "message": "Unauthorized"} (use the muteHttpExceptions option to examine the complete answer) (line 8, file "Code")

So I would like help finding out if there is another easy way or what I need to learn to be able to establish a connection to `apiary.io REST API v1+`.

Comment: Review `urlfetchapp` official documentation and FAQ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script+urlfetch?sort=frequent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a friend developer, we solve with the following solution:

```
   function myFunction() {

      var token = 'Q3VydGl1IGVzc2Ugam9iPyEgdHJhYmFsaGVjb25vc2NvQHBpcGUucnVu'
      var url = 'https://api.pipe.run/v1/deals'
      var params = { method:"GET",
                    headers:{Token: token,
                            contentType:'application/json',}
                    };

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

     var json = response.getContentText();
     var data = JSON.parse(json);
     Logger.log(response.getContentText());

    }
```